# Is the coefficient of restitution of a bouncing ball constant with respect to height?

Tags: energy, momentum, collision, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

Is the rebound rate (or ratio) of a bouncing ball actually constant?

Edit: To clarify, I am considering a given ball and whether it has a different coefficient of restitution depending on the height dropped from (or velocity at impact).

It’s quite typical for high school mathematics textbooks to ask questions about a bouncing ball for the topic of geometric sequences. At this level of education, the maximum height of a bouncing ball is modelled as a geometric progression or exponential function. For instance, $h_{n}=h_{n-1}\times r=h_0\times r^n$, where $h_n$ is the maximum height after the $n$th bounce after it is dropped from a height of $h_0$, and $0< r < 1$ is the rebound rate (coefficient of restitution).

But is $r$ constant with respect to height? Why or why not?

If $r$ is not constant, how do other factors besides gravity and idealised elastic behaviour influence the $(h_0, r)$ relationship? For a typical ball dropped from a typical height, what association should we expect to see? How about in a vacuum to isolate deformation effects?

Comment: Do you have access to a physics book?

Comment: I do not have access to any undergraduate or higher physics textbooks.

Comment: Here's a good place to start: https://www.scienceabc.com/pure-sciences/coefficient-of-restitution-definition-explanation-and-formula.html

Comment: So ‘rebound rate’ is formally referred to as ‘coefficient of restitution’. Then the question could be, is the coefficient of restitution constant for a given ball? And if not, how does height in particular (or velocity on impact) affect the coefficient of restitution? I hadn’t considered sound, but in a vacuum that would be zero along with aerodynamic forces.

Comment: The coefficient of restitution is assumed constant.  The velocity after impact determines how high the ball bounces.

Comment: That’s true for a typical high school physics question. But that’s not my question here.

Comment: Then I suggest you obtain some video capture software, conduct an experiment, and do the calculations to answer your question.

Comment: Not really helpful. I don’t have a vacuum chamber, let alone one 10 metres high. Nor the precision instruments to get accurate results. However, I am going to have a go anyway. But an experiment still won’t answer why, which is the question.

Comment: The "why" may well involve characteristics of the material that the bouncing object is made of.  Answering that question to your satisfaction is going to be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not constant. It decreases with the drop height.

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Khairul-Ismail-6/publication/260991737_Coefficient_of_restitution_of_sports_balls_A_normal_drop_test/links/57a021d808aec29aed214c06/Coefficient-of-restitution-of-sports-balls-A-normal-drop-test.pdf?origin=publication_detail

[image]

Why? Because the coefficient of restitution depends not only on the material of the object but also on its shape.
So when you increase the speed, some object might deform a lot at the impact so can't restitute the kinetic energy the same way than at lower speed.